# Alert Python Selenium, Chrome WebDriver: switch to alert doesn't work

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, popup, alert

Dismissing the alert doesn't work. I get an error every time, I'm using python and working with chrome webdriver. Passing login and password works fine.

I would really appreciate some help:) Thanks:D

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
browser = webdriver.Chrome('My chromedriver path')
a = 1
while a == 1:
try:

browser.get('https://www.facebook.com/')
time.sleep(2)
l = browser.find_element_by_id('email')
l.send_keys('myphonenumber')
l = browser.find_element_by_id('pass')
l.send_keys('myspassword')
l = browser.find_element_by_id('loginbutton')
l.click()
time.sleep(7)

#code works to here and then breaks with error  

b = browser.switch_to.alert()
b.dismiss()
time.sleep(2)

l = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="js_9p"]/div/div/ul/li[1]/a')
time.sleep(2)
l.click()

except:
print('error occured, trying again')
```

This is the error I get:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoAlertPresentException: 
Message: no such alert
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.149)
```

Comment: Check facebook policies if you it's legal to use automation scripts on it.

Comment: When I execute your code, there is no alert? `NoAlertPresentException` agrees with me :) What do you see on the screen when it fails? A screenshot of the HTML would be helpful too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `chrome_options`, it will suppress the notification.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
preferences = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", preferences)

browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver, chrome_options=options)
browser.get('https://www.facebook.com/')
time.sleep(2)
l = browser.find_element_by_id('email')
l.send_keys('username')
l = browser.find_element_by_id('password')
l.send_keys('password')
l = browser.find_element_by_id('loginbutton')
l.click()
time.sleep(7)
```

Comment: Thank you all for your support:D Supressing notifications worked just fine:)